# Servertag not well formed, can't see whats wrong?

Tags: asp.net

Okay I'm almost about to quit this ASP.NET SHYTE.. ;(
I usually code clients and everything is very straightforward.. but this!?!

I don't know how many problems I ahde to work my way through... Anyways I get a PARSER ERROR, SERVER TAG NOT WELL FORMED.

I have been searching the net for a couple of hour, the tips I found range from telling me too use single quotes, to retire as a programmer...

Im trying to display a group of radiobuttons, with data fetched from my database.

codebehind looks like this..

```
protected void fillRepeater()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Server=hide.my.url;Database=no_database;Uid=topsecretuser;Pwd=topsecret");
        con.Open();
       //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + con.State + "');", true);

        string sqlQ = "Select * from t_domains";

        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlQ, con);

        MySqlDataReader dataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        Repeater1.DataSource = dataReader;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        con.Close();

    }
```

This is my HTML. I havent implemented my table rows/cells yet.. (so don't remind me) ;)

```
  Repeater data!<br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>  
    <table>  
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>" value="50" Text="Free access" onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);"  />
     <br />
    <asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton2"  GroupName="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>" 
        Text="Once a day(30/month)" value="25" onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" />
         <br />
    <asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton3" GroupName="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>"  value="0"
        Text="Enter number of articles" onclick="enableTB(this.name, this.checked)" />
         <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" name="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>" Enabled="false" Width="106px" 
        onkeyup="calculatePrice()" style="background-color:#eeeeee" ></asp:TextBox>




    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

ERROR IT GIVES ME
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Source Error:

```
   Line 36:   <asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="         <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>" value="50" Text="Free access" onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);"  />
```

Comment: ...or depending less on the controls and more on outputing simple HTML. I've never found the controls apart from repeater to be as useful as one might hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the " before a <%# with a ' instead. This will prevent you " in the Eval portion from improperly ending your string.

```
<asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>' value="50" Text="Free access" onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);"  />
 <br />
<asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton2"  GroupName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>' 
    Text="Once a day(30/month)" value="25" onclick="calculatePrice();disableTB(this.name);" />
     <br />
<asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton3" GroupName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>'  value="0"
    Text="Enter number of articles" onclick="enableTB(this.name, this.checked)" />
     <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox" name='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idtag_domain") %>' Enabled="false" Width="106px" 
    onkeyup="calculatePrice()" style="background-color:#eeeeee" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespace between `GroupName="` and `<%`.